# Speeding up double NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I am looking to speed up an integral of the type
$$
I(\omega,k,\mu,a,T,\eta) = \int_{-1}^1dx \int_0^{\infty}dq \,\frac{N_F(\sqrt{k^2+q^2+2kqx}-\mu)q^2f(k,q,x)}{(k^2+q^2+2kqx)^{3/2}(\omega+i\eta-q-a\sqrt{k^2+q^2+2kqx})},
$$
where
$$
N_F(x) = \frac{1}{e^{x/T}+1}
$$
is the Fermi-Dirac distribution and 
$$
f(k,q,x) = p_1(x)k^4 + p_2(x)k^3q+p_3(x)q^4 + p_4(x)k^2q^2+p_5(x)kq^3,
$$
with $p_i(x)$ polynomials of $x$ up to fourth order.

In the end I want to evaluate the integral on a grid of values for $(\omega,k)$ and subsequently make a ListDensityPlot of $(\omega,k,\text{Im}[I])$ and $(\omega,k,\text{Re}[I])$. However, the numerical evaluation of the integral takes too long to be able to make a fine enough grid. The code I am using is the following (I evaluate for $z = \omega + i\eta$)

```
NFD[x_, \[Mu]_, T_] := 1/(Exp[(x - \[Mu])/T] + 1) 
ftest1[z_, k_, \[Mu]_, a_, T_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  NFD[Sqrt[k^2 + q^2 + 2 k q x], \[Mu], T]/(Sqrt[
    k^2 + q^2 + 2 k q x])^3 q^2 ((
    2 k^4 (1 + x) + 2 k^3 q (1 + x) (3 + x) + 
     q^4 (1 + x) (7 - 6 x + x^2) - 
     3 k^2 q^2 (1 + x) (-3 - 2 x + x^2) + 
     2 k q^3 (1 + x) (3 + 6 x - 6 x^2 + x^3))/(
    z - q - a Sqrt[k^2 + q^2 + 2 k q x])), {x, -1, 1}, {q, 
   0, \[Infinity]}]
```

Typical values I am using are $\omega \in [-5,5]$, $k\in [0,1]$, $\mu=1$, $a\in[0,1]$, $T=0.02$ and $\eta = 1/1000$ and then the integral can take up to a second to evaluate for one value of $\omega$ and $k$. Any ideas to speed up this numerical evaluation?

Comment: I see that you have "\[Mu]_" inside the `NIntegrate`.  Is this a mistake?

Comment: No, it is input for the FD distribution. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @mikado means the `μ_` that is inside the call to `NFD` inside the definition of `ftest1`.  This should be a `μ` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course, I changed it! Any ideas on speeding up the numerical evaluation of the integral?

Answer (score 2):

We can lower the computation time by an order of magnitude using `ParallelTable[]` and `PrecisionGoal -> 3`

```
NFD[x_, \[Mu]_, T_] := 1/(Exp[(x - \[Mu])/T] + 1)
ftest1[z_, k_, \[Mu]_, a_, T_, op___] := 
 NIntegrate[
  NFD[Sqrt[k^2 + q^2 + 2 k q x], \[Mu], 
     T]/(Sqrt[k^2 + q^2 + 2 k q x])^3 q^2 ((2 k^4 (1 + x) + 
       2 k^3 q (1 + x) (3 + x) + q^4 (1 + x) (7 - 6 x + x^2) - 
       3 k^2 q^2 (1 + x) (-3 - 2 x + x^2) + 
       2 k q^3 (1 + x) (3 + 6 x - 6 x^2 + x^3))/(z - q - 
       a Sqrt[k^2 + q^2 + 2 k q x])), {x, -1, 1}, {q, 0, \[Infinity]},
   op]
```

Plot `Im`

```
With[{\[Mu] = 1, T = .02, a = .5, z2 = I/1000}, 
 lst2 = ParallelTable[{z1, k, 
    Im[Quiet[
      ftest1[z1 + z2, k, \[Mu], a, T, PrecisionGoal -> 3]]]}, {z1, -5,
     5, .1}, {k, 0, 1, .1}]; 
 ListContourPlot[Flatten[lst2, 1], Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "k"}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]]
```

Plot `Re`

```
With[{\[Mu] = 1, T = .02, a = .5, z2 = I/1000}, 
 lst1 = ParallelTable[{z1, k, 
    Re[Quiet[
      ftest1[z1 + z2, k, \[Mu], a, T, PrecisionGoal -> 3]]]}, {z1, -5,
     5, .1}, {k, 0, 1, .1}]; 
 ListContourPlot[Flatten[lst1, 1], Contours -> 20, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, FrameLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "k"}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]]
```

[image: fig1]